# How can I restrict a query that uses STUFF to only return one record for each group of values stuffed rather than one for each stuffed item?

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, self-join

With this query:

```
SELECT S.Unit, LU.ReportName, S.NextExecution, 
       STUFF((SELECT ','+EmailAddr FROM ReportsUnitEmails E WHERE S.Unit = E.Unit AND S.ReportID = E.ReportID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS AllEmailAddresses, 
       S.NextExecutionsBeginDateArg, S.NextExecutionsEndDateArg 
FROM ReportsScheduler S 
FULL JOIN ReportsLU LU ON S.ReportID = LU.ReportID 
FULL JOIN ReportsUnitEmails E on S.Unit = E.Unit AND S.ReportID = E.ReportID 
ORDER BY S.Unit, S.ReportID
```

...I want to get the same count of records as what exists in the RreportsScheduler table, but I am in fact getting one record for each related Email Address (EmailAddr FROM ReportsUnitEmails).

Where there is one email address, one record is returned; where there are four email addresses, four records are returned; etc.

So the question is: can I "distinctify" the complex query to only return one record for each email address (while still stuffing them all into "AllEmailAddresses").

I tried this:

```
SELECT S.Unit, LU.ReportName, S.NextExecution, 
       DISTINCT(STUFF((SELECT ','+EmailAddr FROM ReportsUnitEmails E WHERE S.Unit = E.Unit AND S.ReportID = E.ReportID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS AllEmailAddresses), 
       S.NextExecutionsBeginDateArg, S.NextExecutionsEndDateArg 
FROM ReportsScheduler S 
FULL JOIN ReportsLU LU ON S.ReportID = LU.ReportID 
FULL JOIN ReportsUnitEmails E on S.Unit = E.Unit AND S.ReportID = E.ReportID 
ORDER BY S.Unit, S.ReportID
```

...but it refuses to comp[ile,ly], saying, "Error 156: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DISTINCT'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'."

Not being a SQLhead, it was just a shot in the dark, anyway.

How can I have all my stuff, but fluffier, not stuffier? I'm wondering if a self join might be in my future, but I don't know if that's really so, and if so, how to implement it.

### UPDATE

Both the accepted answer and this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.Unit, LU.ReportName, S.NextExecution, S.ReportID,
       STUFF((SELECT ','+EmailAddr FROM ReportsUnitEmails E WHERE S.Unit = E.Unit AND S.ReportID = E.ReportID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS AllEmailAddresses, 
       S.NextExecutionsBeginDateArg, S.NextExecutionsEndDateArg
FROM ReportsScheduler S 
FULL JOIN ReportsLU LU ON S.ReportID = LU.ReportID 
FULL JOIN ReportsUnitEmails E on S.Unit = E.Unit AND S.ReportID = E.ReportID 
ORDER BY S.Unit, S.ReportID
```

...work, but I'm going with the accepted answer, as it seems "more better."

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies at the row level, not column level. You can only have `DISTINCT` right after the `SELECT` keyword, and it means that duplicate rows will be filtered.

Comment: Just take out the `FULL JOIN ReportsUnitEmails`

Comment: @JamieD77: No, I needed that to get the records for which no email recipients were added.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I'd recommend you research LEFT JOIN for cases where you want the Parent record regardless of whether it has Child records

Comment: Indeed both work and and the accepted answer is better as it doesn't have to filter the duplicates. Less work, better query!

Comment: I appreciate that clay =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need the `ReportsUnitEmails` table inside the subquery you `STUFF`. I commented out the join to `ReportsUnitEmails` in the outer query. That should work.

```
SELECT S.Unit, LU.ReportName, S.NextExecution, 
       STUFF((SELECT ','+EmailAddr FROM ReportsUnitEmails E WHERE S.Unit = E.Unit AND S.ReportID = E.ReportID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS AllEmailAddresses, 
       S.NextExecutionsBeginDateArg, S.NextExecutionsEndDateArg 
FROM ReportsScheduler S 
FULL JOIN ReportsLU LU ON S.ReportID = LU.ReportID 
--FULL JOIN ReportsUnitEmails E on S.Unit = E.Unit AND S.ReportID = E.ReportID 
ORDER BY S.Unit, S.ReportID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DISTINCT should be followed by SELECT Statement. You cannot have DISTINCT before SELECT. Try using DISTINCT along with SELECT Statements.

Comment: "Your DISTINCT should be followed by SELECT Statement. You cannot have DISTINCT before SELECT. " These statements contradict each other.